# How to enable cold storage on AWS Elasticsearch (opensearch) with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform, opensearch

I see option to enable Warm data nodes with [warm_enabled](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_domain), but I haven't seen such an option to enable Cold Storage. I wonder if Terraform supports this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that the Terraform team is still working on it https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19593